# Indy TCPServer Freeze : Active => False

Tags: delphi, server, indy, freeze

I'm trying to find why my application freezes when i run:
    IdTCPServer1.Active := False;

When no client is connected, there is no problem.
When one or more client is connected, it freezes.

If someone can find where I've made a mistake.
(I'm new to Delphi, if you see something else wrong, or doing it in the wrong way ... tell me)

```
 TLog = class(TIdSync)
        protected
            FMsg: String;
            procedure DoSynchronize; override;
        public
            constructor Create(const AMsg: String);
            class procedure AddMsg(const AMsg: String);
        end;


procedure TLog.DoSynchronize;
  begin
    Form2.AddInfoDebugger( 'RECEPTION', FMsg );
  end;


class procedure TLog.AddMsg( const AMsg : String );
  begin
    with Create( AMsg ) do
      try
        Synchronize;
      finally
        Free;
      end;
  end;


constructor TLog.Create( const AMsg : String );
  begin
    FMsg := AMsg;
    inherited Create;
  end;


  /// TFORM 2 ///

constructor TForm2.Create( AOwner : TComponent );
  begin
    inherited Create( AOwner );
    LoadIniConfiguration;

    IdTCPServer1.ContextClass := TMyContext;
    IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort := IndyServerPort;
    DictionaryMessage := TDictionaryMessage.Create;

    fSvrClose := False;

    if fileexists( SaveFileName )
    then
      DictionaryMessage.LoadFromFile( SaveFileName );
    UpdateListQuestions;
    if IndyAutoStart
    then
      StartStopIndyServer;

    // add info state debug save
    if DebugConfigState
    then
      LabelStateDebugSave.Caption :=
        'Sauvegarde des journaux sur disque: Activé'
    else
      LabelStateDebugSave.Caption :=
        'Sauvegarde des journaux sur disque: Désactivé';

  end;


procedure TForm2.FormClose(
  Sender     : TObject;
  var action : TCloseAction );
  var
    iA : integer;
    Context : TIdContext;
  begin
    if IdTCPServer1.Active
    then
    begin
      fSvrClose := true;
      IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
      fSvrClose := False;
    end;

  end;

// ******
// ******INDY procedures START*******//
// ******


procedure TForm2.StartStopIndyServer;
  begin
    if not IdTCPServer1.Active
    then
    begin
      IdTCPServer1.Active := true;
      Form2.AddInfoDebugger( 'ONLINE',
        'Server is now connected and ready to accept clients' );
      ListBoxClients.Clear;
      ListBoxClients.Items.Add( 'Serveur' );
      UpdateCountClients;
      Button1.Caption := 'Arret';
    end
    else
    begin
      fSvrClose := true;
      IdTCPServer1.Active := False;
      fSvrClose := False;
      ListBoxClients.Clear;
      Form2.AddInfoDebugger( 'Offline', 'Server is now disconnected' );
      Button1.Caption := 'Démarrer';
      UpdateCountClients;
    end;
  end;


procedure TForm2.tsConnect( AContext : TIdContext );
  begin
    with TMyContext( AContext ) do
    begin
      Con := Now;
      if ( Connection.Socket <> nil )
      then
        IP := Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;

      Nick := Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
      if Nick <> ''
      then
      begin
        Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn( 'Welcome ' + Nick + '!' );
        ListBoxClients.Items.Add( Nick );

      end
      else
      begin
        Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn( 'No Nick provided! Goodbye.' );
        Connection.Disconnect;
      end;
    end;
  end;


procedure TForm2.tsExecute( AContext : TIdContext );
  var
    FMsg, FMSG2, FMSG3, msg, str, toname, filename, cmd, from,
      orsender : string;
    FStream, fstream2 : TFileStream;
    MStream : TMemoryStream;
    idx, posi, col : integer;
    Name1, Name2, Name3, MainStr : string;
    RXStreamRichedit, DictionaryMessageStream : TStringStream;
    LStreamSize : int64;
  begin
        //Empty for test//
  end;


procedure TForm2.tsDisconnect( AContext : TIdContext );
  begin
    AContext.Connection.Socket.InputBuffer.Clear;
    AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
    TLog.AddMsg( TMyContext( AContext ).Nick + ' Left the chat' );
    ListBoxClients.Items.Delete
      ( ListBoxClients.Items.IndexOf( TMyContext( AContext ).Nick ) );
  end;
```

**[EDIT]**

The problem is with ListBoxClients in tsConnect and tsDisconnect.
I'm looking for a way to make it ThreadSafe.

Comment: Side note: put the classes and their implementations in separated files! The code would be more readable

Comment: This is WAY TOO MUCH code to shift through. Please reduce it to a [mcve] that reproduces the same problem. But I can tell you that the most common reason for the `Active` setter to freeze is if you deadlock your code by performing a *synchronous* sync operation (`TThread.Synchronize()`, `TIdSync`, etc) to the main thread while it is waiting for the server to deactivate. Either use an *asynchronous* sync operation (`TThread.Queue()`, `TIdNotify`, etc), or else deactivate the server in a worker thread. Unless your server threads need a response from the main thread, don't use *synchronous* syncs

Comment: I try to do it today.

Comment: I've edited the code (put it in order, and clean), i hope it's good for you.
It freeze when i stop it manually with 'StartStopIndyServer' or when i close the form.

Comment: @benda: it is still too much code. Pay attention to the **MINIMAL** portion of [mcve]. In any case, I do see code that is not thread-safe, such as `tsConnect()` and`tsDisconnect()` accessing `ListBoxClients` without syncing with the main UI thread. And I see various other code logic that is written synchronously when it could/should be asynchronous instead. BTW, your `WaitExecuteFinish` loops are useless, get rid of them.

Comment: About WaitExecuteFinish, i'm going to remove it.
Is it possible to have a link with informations about 'Syncing' ?

Comment: It drive me crazy.
I've update the code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Any idea ?

Comment: After i've remove everything in `tsExecute`, Still hang.
So i've removed `ListBoxClients` line in `tsDisconnect()` and `tsConnect()`, and it work well.
I'm looking to make it Thread-Safe, how can i transform my `ListBoxClients` ?
I think i've to do it like with `Tlog`, but don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

Remy Lebeau was right !

> I do see code that is not thread-safe, such as tsConnect()
>   andtsDisconnect() accessing ListBoxClients without syncing with the
>   main UI thread.

I've been able to solve my problem with by using :

```
  TLog = class( TIdSync )
    protected
      FMsg : String;
      procedure DoSynchronize; override;
    public
      constructor Create( const AMsg : String );
      class procedure ProcessMsg( const AMsg : String );
  end;


procedure TLog.DoSynchronize;
var
posi: integer;
MsgCommand, ContentCommand: string;
  begin
    posi := Pos( '@', FMsg );
    MsgCommand := Copy( FMsg, 1, posi - 1 );
    ContentCommand := Copy( FMsg, Pos( '@', FMsg ) + 1, Length( FMsg ) - Pos( '@', FMsg ) );

    if MsgCommand = 'AddListBox' then
      Form2.ListBoxClients.items.Add( ContentCommand )
    else if MsgCommand = 'DelListBox' then
      Form2.ListBoxClients.Items.Delete(Form2.ListBoxClients.Items.IndexOf( ContentCommand ));


  end;


class procedure TLog.ProcessMsg( const AMsg : String );
  begin
    if not fSvrClose then
    begin
      with Create( AMsg ) do
        try
          Synchronize;
        finally
          Free;
        end;
    end;
  end;


constructor TLog.Create( const AMsg : String );
  begin
    FMsg := AMsg;
    inherited Create;
  end;
```

And changing my `tsConnect` and `tsDisconnect`

```
TLog.ProcessMsg('AddListBox@'+Nick);
```

Don't know if it is the right way, but it works.